# How to access "this" marker in google map event?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have an arbitrary number of Google Maps markers. I am looping through them and adding event listeners:

```
for ( i in markers )
{
  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'dragend', function()
  {
    console.log( this ); //<-- this doesn't work
  }
}
```

using `this` doesn't seem to work. Also tried:

```
for ( i in markers )
{
  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'dragend', function()
  {
    console.log( markers[i] ); //<-- this doesn't work either
  }
}
```

How can I access the relative marker object who's event is being fired?

Comment: The latter case won't work because new variables are *only* introduced with new function scopes so it is the *same* `i` variable in each callback (plenty of duplicates there). The traditional "double closure" would work, as would "function context binding". However, perhaps the Google Map API has a standard way for this situation - any arguments passed to the callback?

Comment: What do you know, [it's already documented by google ..](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) (the documentation used a named function to create a new variable bindings, not an anonymous closure, and it doesn't show the use of Function.bind or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example should work as expected, but there is a syntax-error, a missing parenthese.

```
for (var i in markers )
{
  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'dragend', function()
  {
    console.log( this); 
  });
//-^
}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/w6HaK/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/w6HaK/)

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that. Thank you.